# Who dug the prophets grave for the burial?

Tags: shiism, shia-sunni, shia-imam

Shia believe Ali (RA) dug forty graves to conceal grave of Fatima.

Sunnis reports quoted in sealed nectar say a person was hired to dig the prophets grave.

The question: who dug the grave of prophet as per twelver shiism?